# Make a extra function in submenu script

Tags: javascript, jquery, submenu

I have a submenu script plugin. Now I want to add an extra function. But I have a few problems. When the submenu is being opened, I want do this:

```
$("body").append('<div id="nav-overlay"></div>');
var nav = $(".submenu").height();
var hoogteNav = $("#nav").height();
$("#nav").height(nav + hoogteNav + 14);
```

And when the submenu being closed, I want to do this:

```
$("#nav-overlay").fadeOut(function() {
    $("#nav-overlay").remove();
});
$("#nav").css({ height: "33px"});
```

But now I have problems with this. When the submenu is open, and you hover over the `li` element. Than the function is opening again and again. You can see this here: [Here](http://regioportals.demo.lostboys.nl/homepage.shtml)

What am I doing wrong?

This is the whole script:

```
(function($) {    
    //define the defaults for the plugin and how to call it 
    $.fn.dcMegaMenu = function(options){
        //set default options  
        var defaults = {
            classParent: 'dc-mega',
            rowItems: 3,
            speed: 'fast',
            effect: 'fade'
        };

        //call in the default otions
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
        var $dcMegaMenuObj = this;

        //act upon the element that is passed into the design    
        return $dcMegaMenuObj.each(function(options) {
            megaSetup();

            function megaOver() {
                var submenuNav = $('.submenu',this);
                $(this).addClass('mega-hover');

                $("body").append( '<div id="nav-overlay"></div>' );

                var nav = $(".submenu").height();
                var hoogteNav = $("#nav").height();
                $("#nav").height(nav + hoogteNav + 14);

                if(defaults.effect == 'fade'){
                    $(submenuNav).fadeIn(defaults.speed);
                }
            }

            function megaOut(){
                var submenuNav = $('.submenu',this);
                $(this).removeClass('mega-hover');
                $("#nav-overlay").fadeOut(function() {
                    $("#nav-overlay").remove();
                });
                $("#nav").css({ height: "33px"});
                $(submenuNav).hide();
            }

            function megaSetup() {
                var classParentLi = defaults.classParent+'-li';
                var menuWidth = $($dcMegaMenuObj).outerWidth(true);
                $('> li',$dcMegaMenuObj).each(function(){
                    //Set Width of submenu
                    var mainsubmenu = $('> ul',this);
                    var primaryLink = $('> a',this);
                    if ($(mainsubmenu).length > 0) {
                        $(primaryLink).addClass(defaults.classParent).append($arrow);
                        $(mainsubmenu).addClass('submenu').wrap('<div class="submenu-container" />');

                        // Get Position of Parent Item
                        var position = $(this).position();
                        parentLeft = position.left;

                        if ($('ul',mainsubmenu).length > 0){
                            $(this).addClass(classParentLi);
                            $('.submenu-container',this).addClass('mega');
                            $('> li',mainsubmenu).addClass('mega-hdr');
                            $('.mega-hdr > a').addClass('mega-hdr-a');
                            // Create Rows
                            var hdrs = $('.mega-hdr',this);
                            rowSize = parseInt(defaults.rowItems);
                            for(var i = 0; i < hdrs.length; i+=rowSize){
                                hdrs.slice(i, i+rowSize).wrapAll('<div class="row" />');
                            }

                            // Get submenu Dimensions & Set Row Height
                            $(mainsubmenu).show();

                            // Calc Left Position of submenu Menu
                            // // Get Width of Parent
                            var parentWidth = $(this).width();

                            // // Calc Width of submenu Menu
                            var submenuWidth = $(mainsubmenu).outerWidth(true);
                            var totalWidth = $(mainsubmenu).parent('.submenu-container').outerWidth(true);
                            var containerPad = totalWidth - submenuWidth;
                            var itemWidth = $('.mega-hdr',mainsubmenu).outerWidth(true);
                            var rowItems = $('.row:eq(0) .mega-hdr',mainsubmenu).length;
                            var innerItemWidth = itemWidth * rowItems;
                            var totalItemWidth = innerItemWidth + containerPad;

                            // Set mega header height
                            $('.row',this).each(function(){
                                $('.mega-hdr:last',this).addClass('last');
                                var maxValue = undefined;
                                $('.mega-hdr-a',this).each(function(){
                                    var val = parseInt($(this).height());
                                    if (maxValue === undefined || maxValue < val){
                                        maxValue = val;
                                    }
                                });
                                $('.mega-hdr-a',this).css('height',maxValue+'px');
                                $(this).css('width',innerItemWidth+'px');
                            });

                            // // Calc Required Left Margin
                            var marginLeft = (totalItemWidth - parentWidth)/2;
                            var submenuLeft = parentLeft - marginLeft;

                            // If Left Position Is Negative Set To Left Margin
                            if(submenuLeft < 0){
                                $('.submenu-container',this).css('left','0');
                            } else {
                                $('.submenu-container',this).css('left',parentLeft+'px').css('margin-left',-marginLeft+'px');
                            }

                            // Calculate Row Height
                            $('.row',mainsubmenu).each(function(){
                                var rowHeight = $(this).height();
                                $('.mega-hdr',this).css('height',rowHeight+'px');
                                $(this).parent('.row').css('height',rowHeight+'px');
                            });

                            $(mainsubmenu).hide();

                        } else {
                            $('.submenu-container',this).addClass('non-mega').css('left',parentLeft+'px');
                        }
                    }
                });
                // Set position of mega dropdown to bottom of main menu
                var menuHeight = $('> li > a',$dcMegaMenuObj).outerHeight(true);
                $('.submenu-container',$dcMegaMenuObj).css({top: menuHeight+'px'}).css('z-index','1000');
                // HoverIntent Configuration
                var config = {
                    sensitivity: 2, // number = sensitivity threshold (must be 1 or higher)
                    interval: 100, // number = milliseconds for onMouseOver polling interval
                    over: megaOver, // function = onMouseOver callback (REQUIRED)
                    timeout: 400, // number = milliseconds delay before onMouseOut
                    out: megaOut // function = onMouseOut callback (REQUIRED)
                };
                $('li',$dcMegaMenuObj).hoverIntent(config);
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Thanks for helping me!!!

Comment: _Btw, I'm not sure your boss will be pleased that you are spreading that url around. But that's offtopic._

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, the megaOver function is firing for the main menu item, as well as the sub menu item. Thats causing the `#nav-overlay` div to appear and disappear. You should separate the mouseOver functions for the main and submenu's somehow.

Or you could modify the function to check if the nav-overlay div is already there:

```
if($('#nav-overlag').length == 0){
   $("body").append( '<div id="nav-overlay"></div>' );
}
```